# initWithFrame doesnt work on my project in IOS 5 but did in IOS 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I made an program from a tutorial in ios 4 which was a checkbox. I had a friend who is starting to program in xcode for iphone. So, I gave him my codes so he can start. Turns out, he was trying to do the code himself in ios5 following the code I made for IOS4. He kept telling me that his didn't work and that he got a bunch of errors some as follows. So I would open my code and ran it on my updated xcode and it ran fine, no problem what so ever. 
The funny thing was when I got to his house and I looked at the code and played around with it. He was right. Trying to do the code from a new project in the new xcode with the new ios, the project would throw all sorts of errors. I posted some in the bottom.

So, my question is this... why is this?
does this have to do with the the way ios5 uses ARC and different properties?

- NSObject may not respond to initWithFrame
- Instance method - setImageForState not found(return type defaults to "id")
- instance method - addTarget:action:forControlEvents not found(return type default to id)
- MicheckBox may not respond to initWithFrame
  and some more

my code is as follows
have to png one called checkbox_ticked.png and a checkbox_not_ticked.png

micheckbox.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MICheckBox : UIButton 
{
BOOL isChecked;
}
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL isChecked;
-(IBAction) checkBoxClicked;
@end
```

micheckbox.m

```
#import "MICheckBox.h"
@implementation MICheckBox
@synthesize isChecked;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) 
    {
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_not_ticked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self 
addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}
-(IBAction) checkBoxClicked
{
if(self.isChecked ==NO)
    {
    self.isChecked =YES;
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_ticked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    else
        {
            self.isChecked =NO;
        [self setImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"checkbox_not_ticked.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
}
- (void)dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

MICheckBoxAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MICheckBoxAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{
    UIWindow *window;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@end
```

MICheckBoxAppDelegate.m

```
#import "MICheckBoxAppDelegate.h"
#import "MICheckBox.h"
@implementation MICheckBoxAppDelegate
@synthesize window;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{    
    // Override point for customization after application launch
    MICheckBox *checkBox =[[MICheckBox alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 80, 150, 30)];
    [checkBox setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkBox setTitle:@"Checkbox" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [window addSubview:checkBox];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
- (void)dealloc 
{
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: This looks like one of those times Xcode just goes wonko with the errors. Generally you want to look at `Show issue navigator` or Command-4 and look at the error (red one) at the top of the list. Also check your imports for misspelling, these error seem to indicate the "MICheckBox.h" header is not being correctly imported. But again check the top error first.

Comment: I would agree with you if i was coding from scratch. But, it is a working copy from my project done last October. And just applying it to a new project in xcode it goes ballistic and starts throwing errors left and right. Btw, just to answer your suggestion i did check and everything seems to be in order with the imports.

Comment: But i do agree... This is one of those times that xcode is going wonko.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to "return self" in the initWithFrame of MICheckBox class.

Comment: its there... just the way the code looks you cant tell. But its there.